# Form not submitted, page not loads when submit button is disabled after click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

When I click the submit button, the page loads for a few seconds and after that the form is finally submitted. I want to stop multiple submits in a short period of time. That is why I use the following jquery to stop multiple submits.

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Submit(this)"/>
```

```
<script>
    function Submit(button)
    {
        var oldValue = button.value;

        button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        button.value = 'processing...';

        setTimeout(function() {
            button.value = oldValue;
            button.removeAttribute('disabled');
        }, 10000)
    }
</script>
```

My problem is when I click the submit button, it disables for few seconds and after that the button is reenabled, but the form is not submitted and also the page does not load.

When I click the submit button on `google chrome`, the button clicks but the page does not load and the form is not submitted. When I click the submit button on `Mozilla Firefox`, the page goes to the form action page and a white page appears.

Comment: Try changing button to type button and not submit

Comment: @achal naskar: Why do you reeanable the button after 10 seconds? This are you doing with your sequence in the setTimeout callback function.

Comment: _"why I use the following jquery"_ - No, you're not using any jQuery in that script. That's all native JavaScript.

Comment: @achal do you use setTimeout to simulate an ajax call or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is, the button is disabled before the submit event is triggered.

Try this:

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

```
$('form#id').submit(function(e) {
    $(this).children('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    e.preventDefault(); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You dont have to write e.preventDefault(); because return false(); do it for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function Submit(button)
    {
        var oldValue = button.value;

        button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        button.value = 'processing...';

        $(button).closest('form').submit();
    }
</script>
```